# Rails 4 - Group by date range on month intervals

Tags: sqlite, date, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, charts

I'm trying to group my Events table my months and in range so i can present it in a chart (i'm using the chartKick gem). The Events have a start_date and a end_date so if a event starts in February and ends in February it will count as a February event, but if the Event starts in February and end in March it will count as a March Event. The format i desire is:

{"JAN"=>2, "FEB"=>3, "MAR"=>5, "APR"=>10, "MAY"=>5, "JUNE"=>0, "JULY"=>12, "AUG"=>4, "SEPT"=>17, "OCT"=>8, "NOV"=>0, "DEC"=>3}

Right now i'm using something very simple that doesn't do what i want:

```
<%= pie_chart Event.group(["DATE(created_at)"]).count %>
```

Can anyone help me getting the right query?

thanks

Comment: you need this: https://github.com/humzashah/convenient_grouper

Comment: thanks for the tip! i've tried: `Event.group({start_time: {Jan: Date.new(2016,1)..Date.new(2016,1,31)}})` but i'm getting: "#<Event::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fe99b92f4f4>
"

Comment: Because you've only grouped them so far. You need to call `.count` on that object, like you have in your example.

Comment: if i try to call `.count` it returns: `TypeError: Cannot visit Range`

Comment: Check for typos and proper gem integration. For example; you're using `created_at` in your question and `start_time` in your code. To quickly check if the gem has been integrated, just run `ModelName.group(created_at: some_date_range).count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Humza, i finally got it, i did like this:

```
<%= pie_chart Event.group({start_time: {Jan: Date.new(2016,1)..Date.new(2016,1,31), Fev: Date.new(2016,2)..Date.new(2016,2,29), MAR: Date.new(2016,3)..Date.new(2016,3,31), APR: Date.new(2016,4)..Date.new(2016,4,30), MAY: Date.new(2016,5)..Date.new(2016,5,31), JUN: Date.new(2016,6)..Date.new(2016,6,30), JUL: Date.new(2016,7)..Date.new(2016,7,31), AUG: Date.new(2016,8)..Date.new(2016,8,31), SEP: Date.new(2016,9)..Date.new(2016,9,30), OCT: Date.new(2016,10)..Date.new(2016,10,31), NOV: Date.new(2016,11)..Date.new(2016,11,30), DEZ: Date.new(2016,12)..Date.new(2016,12,31)}}).count %>
```

Comment: I tried above in rails5 but it didn't work for me.
I got below error.
```Arel::Visitors::UnsupportedVisitError: Unsupported argument type: Hash. Construct an Arel node instead.```